# Load dll with Platform target 'Any CPU' in Python

Tags: c#, python, dll, corflags

I have a dll which was built with platform target 'Any CPU'. I am trying to write a Python script which loads this dll and getting an 'Could not load assembly or one of its dependencies' error message.
I tried CorFlag.exe and got following output

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32+
CorFlags  : 0x9
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 1

Do both Python 32 and 64 bit versions load the dll with 'Any CPU' platform target?

**Update:**
I am using Python for .NET to refer a dll from GAC and this dll in turn loads the implementation from an assembly from installation directory. Its from this assembly I get an exception. The same script works fine in Python x86, but not in x64.

Comment: Are you using IronPython? I believe a .NET dll can only be loaded into a .NET application.

Comment: No Python 2.7. I using clr.Addreference to refer the dll.

Comment: Are you using [Python for .NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) then? `clr` is not a standard module.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question.